# DOMPDF - PHP-HTML to PDF conversion?

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have a php file of which I want to generate a PDF using dompdf, I have tried it  with the code below but I can't get the html of the file from php, any idea on how to get the html elements from php file?

```
    <?php
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    ob_start();        
    ?>
    <html>
     <body>
     <?php
         //Code for a colored table
     ?>
     <form method=post action=#><input type=submit name=submit id=submit value="Create PDF"></form>
     </body>
    <html>

    <?php
        if((isset($_POST['submit'])))
        {
            $html = ob_get_contents(); 
                ob_end_flush();
            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            $dompdf->stream("Time Table.pdf");
        }
    ?>
```

**EDIT:**
It now gives an error:

Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in .../

Comment: I don't see anything out of sorts here. What do you get when you submit the form? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Fatal Error: Maximum execution time 30 seconds exceeded

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much this matters but your html closing tag is actually just another open html tag. Try closing it and changing your code to the following :

```
 <?php
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    ob_start();        
    ?>
    <html>
     <body>
     <?php
         //Code for a colored table
     ?>
     <form method=post action=#><input type=submit name=submit id=submit value="Create PDF"></form>
     </body>
    </html>

    <?php
        if((isset($_POST['submit'])))
        {
            $html = ob_get_contents(); 
                ob_end_flush();
            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            $dompdf->stream("Time Table.pdf");
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, my code generates pdf but is a corrupted pdf file! also it give fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeds 30s

Comment: @TKA If the PDF is corrupted some PHP errors/notices may be leaking into the output stream. Save the PDF and open it in a text editor to see if that's the case. The errors will be at the top of the file.

Comment: @BrianS but I do get the result when I echo the $html

Comment: @TKA as I said, a corrupted PDF is often because some non-PDF content is injected into the output stream. That doesn't mean the HTML is invalid, or even that the PDF is invalid. It just means there is extra, non-PDF content interfering with your PDF reader's parsing of the document. You could just comment out `$dompdf->stream()` and see what is returned.